# Gateway Xor Unnecessary

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bizagi

I wanted to know if the XOR-gateway used in join mode in this case is needed or not, thanks

The process starts, subsequently based on a condition (not specified in the picture), the "Task 1" activity is performed or no activity is performed. After the process must terminate.
[process under consideration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X45Wn.png)
I tried this solution, but i'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one token, then I don't see reason why to close flow with additional gateway.
In your scenario, I would model process as follows:

- Start event, followed by gateway that evaluates if Task 1 should or should not be executed
- Flow to end event 1 if Task 1 should not be executed
- Flow to Task 1, followed by End event 2